# Magento2 - How to get base url in js file added to backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, base-url

I have try to get base url using mage/url in my custom `js` , but it return url without base url so,
is there any another way using that we can get magento base url in js which is added in admin side ?

Comment: You can get by pass url from phtml file and get into js file.

Comment: thanks @Rohan , this is the one way we can do and working great !!!

Comment: is there any another way that we can get solution with single js file without using phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mage/url` widget is not used to fetch backend base URL in Magento 2.

You need to create a template file using layout XML and define the base URL of backend under the template file.

You can define any Global variable and set your URL in it.

Create a simple layout XML file to fetch backend URL of the site using JS,

Create 
`default.xml`
 file for global access at admin area or create a specific action layout file for a specific page,

```
File Path:  app/code/VendorName/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
```

Code Content:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="js">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="VendorName_MyModule::js.phtml"
                       name="custom_js_backend"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Now Create js.phtml file,

```
File Path: app/code/VendorName/MyModule/view/adminhtml/templates/js.phtml
```

Code Content:

```
<script>
        require([
            "prototype"
        ], function () {
            window.customUrl = "<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('frontname/index/index')?>";
            var customUrl = window.customUrl;
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In phtml file add this code:

```
         <input type="hidden" id="testUrl" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>"/>
```

By using Id we can get base url in JS file

```
             $("#testUrl").val();
```

Hope it will help